# Cummulative Circle rotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I have a rotation of a circle that goes from 0 to 360 an back to 0 to 360 and so on. Now i want to now the cumulative degree so that i get 0 to 360 an to 720 and so on.

so i have a 2 variables

```
var rotation = <goes from 0-360>
var cumulativeRotation = <should go from 0-+360>
```

rotation is know, cumulativeRotation should be calculated.

My first thought was to remember the previousRotation and substract it from rotation and add that to the cumulativeRotation, but when you go from 360 back to 0, you break the circle

is there a easy way to overcome that issue?

Comment: Are you asking about a rotation animation that repeats and adds to the previous rotation (as opposed to using absolute values)?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply iterate the `cumulativeRotation`, and calculate `rotation` from it, by dividing it modulo 360?

Comment: because i only have the current rotation of my uiview calculated with atan2 and it goes from 0-360

Answer (score 0):

What's the problem with having a separate property? That sounds fine, as long as you strictly manage it.

```
- (void)setCumulativeRotation:(NSInteger)cumulativeRotation
{
    if (cumulativeRotation > 719 || cumulativeRotation < 0)
        cumulativeRotation = 0;

    _cumulativeRotation = cumulativeRotation;
}
```

You can also override the setter for `.rotation` to keep track of how many times it passes through 0 (or 360), although there's no way to robustly handle situations where the rotation is set to an arbitrary value:

```
- (void)setRotation:(NSInteger)rotation
{
    if ( _rotation > rotation)
    {
        // counter-clockwise
        if (rotation < 0)
            self.numberOfRevolutions--;
    } else if (_rotation < rotation)
    {
        // clockwise
        if (rotation > 719)
            self.numberOfRevolutions++;
    }
    _rotation = rotation;
}
```

Something like that?